# NSMutable Array High CPU Usage

Tags: ios, objective-c

I recently change c array to NSMutable array because I had a lot of troubles with memory. However it works, but starting from

```
/* If two starttimes are within interval millisec, make them the same */
for (int i = 0; i < [starttimes count] - 1; i++) {
   if ([[starttimes objectAtIndex:i+1] integerValue] - [[starttimes objectAtIndex:i] integerValue] <= interval) {
        [starttimes insertObject: [starttimes objectAtIndex:i] atIndex:(i+1)];
    }
}
```

CPU usage is nearly 100%. I do not know what is going on? The logic is fairly simple. All it does is to get two elements from this NSMutable array, then compare and insert. BTW, this chunk of codes never stop. It keeps running 3 seconds, then my app crashes.

```
(TimeSignature*)time {
/* Get all the starttimes in all tracks, in sorted order */
NSInteger initsize = 1;
if ([tracks count] > 0) {
    MidiTrack *track = [tracks objectAtIndex:0];
    initsize = [track.notes count];
    initsize = initsize * [tracks count]/2;
}
NSMutableArray* starttimes = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:initsize];

for (int tracknum = 0; tracknum < [tracks count]; tracknum++) {

    NSLog(@"tracknum is %d",tracknum);
    MidiTrack *track = [tracks objectAtIndex:tracknum];
     NSLog(@"WE ARE HERE %ld",(long)initsize);
    for (int j = 0; j < [track.notes count]; j++) {
        MidiNote *note = [track.notes objectAtIndex:j];

        NSLog(@"%@",note);
        [starttimes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:note.startTime]];
    }
}


/* Notes within "millisec" milliseconds apart should be combined */
int interval = time.quarter * millisec * 1000 / time.tempo;

/* If two starttimes are within interval millisec, make them the same */
for (int i = 0; i < [starttimes count] - 1; i++) {
    if ([[starttimes objectAtIndex:i+1] integerValue] - [[starttimes objectAtIndex:i] integerValue] <= interval) {
        [starttimes insertObject: [starttimes objectAtIndex:i] atIndex:(i+1)];
    }

}
```

Thanks so much

Comment: FYI - the `if` statement if the 1st block is code is terribly incorrect. You can't cast the object pointers to `NSInteger` and expect the comparison to work as expected.

Comment: you are right, I changed it to if ([[starttimes objectAtIndex:i+1] integerValue] - [[starttimes objectAtIndex:i] integerValue] <= interval) {
            [starttimes insertObject: [starttimes objectAtIndex:i] atIndex:(i+1)];
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General Objective-C advice: read the method names. They tell you want the methods do.

You've misunderstood `-insertObject:`. What `insertObject` does is... **insert** an object. What it does not do: replace an object. You're increasing the size of the array every time you call `insertObject`. In practice you're creating an infinite loop should the `if` condition pass even once.

You probably wanted `-replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:`. Which, like `insertObject:`, will do what the name says.

Comment: I just figure it out.Yes, it should be replace instead of insert. Anyway, thanks.